# Don't understand how this let-let-lambda works

Tags: scheme

I'm back with another scheme question. This is an example from Dybvig's book *The Scheme Programming Language*, and I understand what is happening:

```
(let ([x 'a])
  (let ([f (lambda (y) (list x y))])
    (f 'b))) --> (a b)
```

However he immediately follows it up with a modified example that I don't understand:

```
(let ([f (let ([x 'sam])
             (lambda (y z) (list x y z)))])
  (f 'i 'am)) --> (sam i am)
```

In the call `(f 'i 'am)` I don't know what's going on, that's my confusion. I don't see how f is defined with two parameters. How do the lambda parameters bubble up, for lack of a better term, to f?? I would think that the code `let ([x 'sam])` would block that from happening. But that isn't the case obviously. I hope my English phrasing of my confusion makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f` is defined as `(lambda (y z) (list x y z))`, where `x` is defined as `'sam`.

Let's break this down a bit.

```
(let ([x 'sam])
    (lambda (y z) (list x y z)))
```

This evaluates to the lambda (which I'll call `that_lambda` because I can).

```
(let ([f that_lambda])
  (f 'i 'am)) --> (sam i am)
```

This evaluates to `(that_lambda 'i 'am)`.

Because `that_lambda` was defined* in the scope* where `x` was `'sam`, `x` used inside `that_lambda` refers to `'sam`.

---

<sup>* It's so long since I've done Lisp that I don't know whether my terms are correct.</sup>

Comment: I don't understand the answer I've just posted... I feel like a Chinese Room!

Comment: Ha, and I am now in the room with you. :) My confusion rests with the y,z parameters. Clearly you can pass in arguments to those parms, but how? Is it correct to say that the variable assignment `[x 'sam]` does not interfere with f getting those y,z parms.? If that makes sense?

Comment: @THedge `f` is set to a `lambda` with parameters `y` and `z`. I'm going to give a wrong explanation using concepts from another programming paradigm, but it should serve to help.

Comment: Kind of wrong explanation: Imagine that everything in the program is a little box. Each little box has a thread attaching it to a "scope", so it can work out what variables are. `let` creates a new scope, and there's a new scope inside `lambda`s too. Each scope has, attached to it, its parent scope. When you look up a variable, you follow the chain of scopes until you find it. `that_lambda` is just a `lambda`, but its scope contains an `x` which is equal to `'sam`. The code in `that_lambda` has a scope where it can see `y` and `z`, which are the parameters passed to `that_lambda` (cont)

Comment: (cont) but that scope is attached to `that_lambda`'s parent scope, which contains an `x` which is equal to `'sam`. So the code running in `that_lambda` can see `x`, `y` and `z`, despite `that_lambda` just being a normal `lambda`. (I should really be calling it `f`, because that's what the program calls it.)

Comment: Your wrong explanation turned on the light bulb when you mentioned scope. That makes me understand what's going on, if I think of the `let` as providing scope. I was making it provide more than that, erroneously, and that was causing my confusion. Thanks. :)